# Power BI Performance issue

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Recently I started creating a dataset in power BI , which is calling a snowflake view and pulling data to power bi, around 160 M records. I have also created 15 or so measure fields where I have used DAX for calculations. Same dataset with measures , completes the refresh in tableau within 1.5 hr where in Power BI it fails after 5 hrs.   Snowflake query execution only takes 7 mins or so with L warehouse to complete the execution of view.

I am not sure , how should I start to improve the performance ? Any ideas ? I can not go for incremental as underlying table of view gets truncated daily with same update timestamp.

Thank you